# how do i add buttons to a ListFragment

Tags: android

Whenever i put the buttons in the xml files for the listFragment layout it is added to the ListView. what i want is to have 2 buttons under the ListView of the fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/peersFragment" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this the ListFragment layout i have. how should i specify that the buttons are under the listView

Comment: Do you mean add 2 buttons to each element? If so, you'd have to use a custom adapter. [Here's an article on ListViews in Android, and about making your own](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown)

Comment: this listview shows other Wifi direct devices. so i want to add a scan button under the listview. to allow users to look for devices.

Comment: Can't you change the RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout and place the buttons underneath in that way?

Comment: the problem is whatever i put in the xml file becomes a part of the ListView. when i added the buttons they were in the lists inside the listView

Comment: You say you're using a ListFragment. How about putting it in the Activity containing the fragment?

Comment: am adding the fragment to the activity dynamically by replacing a frame layout. so am not sure thats possible

Comment: Can't you still place the two buttons below the FrameLayout? That is, in the Activity's layout file, place the two buttons below the FrameLayout element

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/peersFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- <TextView -->
    <!-- android:id="@+id/android:empty" -->
    <!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
    <!-- android:layout_height="match_parent" /> -->
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Device Name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Device Address" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the buttons were added inside of the ListView